# Search IndexComponent is becoming too large

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, crawl, searchserviceapplication, index-component

I have a problem with a Search Service IndexComponent where it has become large enough to cover up the whole of the Local System Drive.
I would like to ask you some question about what are the actions that i can take in order to minify its contents.

1. Should i reset the index? By doing so, will i delete all of the indexcomponent contents and refill them with a full crawl?
2. I know that i can migrate it to another drive, but it is increasing its space and eventually i will have to fix space issues on the new drive, thats why it is not a viable solution
3. is there someway of validating the data that the indexcomponent has? if they point to deleted files are they deleted on a full crawl?
4. Currently, a full crawl is run on a weekly basis. Isn't just incremental crawls on a daily basis enough?

Thanks in advance for the help Community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset, but likely the index will grow to the ~same size as you just need that large of an index. Moving it to its own volume provides performance improvements, so that's good practice anyways.

You shouldn't need to run full crawls. Set up Continuous Crawl and be done with it. Full crawls are only used for troubleshooting, initial crawl, or adding/manipulating Managed Properties at the SSA level (though you should be doing so at the Site level if possible).

Comment: Thanks for the anwer Trevor.
I would like to ask you a question. What happens if a crawled document is deleted?
Are the metadata, that were crawled regarding the document, still persised?
Is the indexcomponent automatically updated to not show info about the deleted item?

Comment: The item is cleaned up from the index when it is deleted.

Comment: Trevor, i would like to ask you another question.
Why would someone enter in the Content Sources addreses the Domain name setup for the sharepoint site and the internal server name?
Would that result in an index with double the numbers of the crawled items?
If i delete the internal server name from the content sources, is it possible for the index to be cleaned up?

Comment: The index will clean itself up. I don't know why someone would have done that. You can check the crawl log for a single item and see if you see two entries.

Comment: Thanks for the response Trevor. I hope that this means that the index component will decrease in disk size also

Comment: Just for the info, the index does save both locations. I searched for entries with <domain>/<subsite>/lists/<list>/dispform.aspx?ID=<ID> and i did find another entries that had the same id <server FQDN>/<subsite>/lists/<list>/dispform.aspx?ID=<ID>.
Absolutely, Disastrous... I think i have an index space of duplicate items...